# How can I bind the text in a NSTextField to the value of a property on a controller using a storyboard?

Tags: cocoa, swift, storyboard, cocoa-bindings

I have a custom view with two text subviews, arranged, not that it matters, as per this amazing ASCII art:

```
/--------\
| lblOne |
| lblTwo |
\--------/
```

On my controller, I have a property of type `Thingy`:

```
class AwesomeController: NSViewController {
    var thingy: Thingy! = nil
}
```

A `Thingy` has two properties of interest:

```
class Thingy: NSObject {
    var one: String
    var two: String
}
```

---

I would like to set up a binding between `lblOne`'s string value and `thingy.one`, and `lblTwo`'s string value and `thingy.two`, going through a custom view class if necessary.

When `thingy` is changed, obviously the two text fields should also change.  (In other words, it should behave normally for a cocoa binding.)

---

I think it's probably a combination of learning Swift and my unfamiliarity with storyboards on OS X (last time I did cocoa development, it was still xibs), but I can't work out how to link the damn thing up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting bindings to work in Swift requires two additional steps:

1. All the vars must be marked with `dynamic`, eg:

   `dynamic var one: String`
2. You have to recompile the project (with cmd+B, not just in the background) in order for the var to appear as an option in IB

Comment: In newer Swift versions, it's also apparently critical to annotate it with `@objc`, or else the view will crash.